# bash script for gnuplot input

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I am using the following lines in a script.

```
foo=$1

bar=$(printf  ' , "%s" u ($1):($2) lw 8 ti' ${foo[@]} ${foo[@]} ${foo[@]} ${foo[@]}   )

bar=${bar:2}

echo $bar
```

This produces the following line as the value of variable bar

```
"rdf_inter_fortran_05-25.xvg" u ($1):($2) lw 8 ti , "rdf_inter_fortran_05-25.xvg" u ($1):($2) lw 8 ti , "rdf_inter_fortran_05-25.xvg" u ($1):($2) lw 8 ti , "rdf_inter_fortran_05-25.xvg" u ($1):($2) lw 8 ti
```

Is it possible to modify the script so the output is:

```
"rdf_inter_fortran_05-25.xvg" u ($1):($2) lw 8 ti , "rdf_inter_fortran_05-25.xvg" u ($1):($3) lw 8 ti , "rdf_inter_fortran_05-25.xvg" u ($1):($4) lw 8 ti , "rdf_inter_fortran_05-25.xvg" u ($1):($5) lw 8 ti
```

Comment: I modified the question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your printf line to the following :

```
bar=$(printf ' , "%s" u ($1):($%s) lw 8 ti' ${foo[@]} "2" ${foo[@]} "3" ${foo[@]} "4" ${foo[@]} "5" )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are replacing some $2's with new strings. Insert this line before `echo $bar` :

```
bar=$(echo $bar | sed 's/$2/$5/4; s/$2/$4/3; s/$2/$3/2;')
```

This replaces the 4th, 3rd and 2nd occurrence of $2 with new respective values $5, $4 and $3.